# Python distributed transactions like Java Transaction API (JTA)

Tags: python, database, transactions, jta

Is there a solution about distributed transactions in Python or the MySQLdb like Java Transaction API (JTA)?

I got a problem when I processing data on multiple databases (maybe different kinds of databases).

How can I ensure data consistency?

I know there's Java Transaction API (JTA) in Java.

How can I do it Python?

Comment: as you may know, a JTA requires a JTS which is provided by an application server and none of all this things exists with python. You can at least have a look at how [django manages transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/)

Comment: yes,the application server.but i can't find it.could't you give me some details?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL statements to do the XA transaction. This is not as pretty as an real API, but it works. I don't know if there are TM's (transaction managers) available for Python, but you could write your own.

Also note that in Java it is not required to use an application server when using XA. An example: http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=22190&bug_id=75316

```
In [1]: import mysql.connector

In [2]: c = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port=5705,user='msandbox',password='msandbox');

In [3]: cur = c.cursor();

In [4]: cur.execute("XA START 'py-xa-001'");

In [5]: cur.execute("INSERT INTO test.t1 VALUES(1)");

In [6]: cur.execute("XA RECOVER");

In [7]: print(cur.fetchone());
None

In [8]: cur.execute("XA END 'py-xa-001'");

In [9]: cur.execute("XA PREPARE 'py-xa-001'");

In [10]: cur.execute("XA RECOVER");

In [11]: print(cur.fetchone());
(1, 9, 0, u'py-xa-001')

In [12]: cur.execute("XA ROLLBACK 'py-xa-001'");

In [13]: cur.close()
Out[13]: True

In [14]: c.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this option myself, but, from a cursory glance, it seems that the `Transaction` library fits the description of what Java's transaction API offers. It's available for download in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transaction) and documented in [read the docs](http://transaction.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)